# RuntimeError: <path> failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config

Tags: macos, llvm, llvmlite

Trying to install `llvmlite` via `pip` by running

```
pip install llvmlite
```

constantly gives me this error:

```
    RuntimeError: <path> failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
    error: command '/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/asr-service/bin/python' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
```

Now, I am on Python 3.5

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

And just running `pip install llvmlite` will give me this:

```
 RuntimeError: Building llvmlite requires LLVM 7.0.x, 7.1.x or 8.0.x, got '10.0.0'. Be sure to set LLVM_CONFIG to the right executable path.
```

I installed LLVM 8 via `brew`

```
brew install llvm@8
```

Setting `LLVM_CONFIG` to either does not work.

- `/usr/local/opt/llvm@8/bin` (were I assumed `llvm-config` to be), or
- `/usr/local/opt/llvm@8/Toolchains/LLVM8.0.1.xctoolchain/usr/bin` (where I actually found `llvm-config` to be)

And I keep getting some version of:

```
RuntimeError: /usr/local/opt/llvm@8/Toolchains/LLVM8.0.1.xctoolchain/usr/bin failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11):

And for those reviewing the post in search for a solution to installing numba, the version released on June 24, 2020 works:
`pip install numba==0.50.1`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why installing `numba` answers the question?

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie in contributing to stack overflow, so this might be a stretch. I was trying to install numba which depends on llvmlite, and the last stable release (of numba) uses the llvmlite version with the bug detailed in the question. My train of thought was that my comment might be helpful to those looking to solve the numba installation problem. In hindsight, I think it might have been more helpful to open a new question for numba specifically and answer that one.

Comment: I still get the error even when using `pip install numba==0.50.1`

Answer (score 9):

Looks like there is an issue with latest version of llvmlite. Please consider using 0.31.0 version.

```
>>pip install llvmlite==0.31.0

Collecting llvmlite==0.31.0
  Downloading 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/31/aa315fbc2e0b7777b95ce166b7c988f53e4cdd4c33d06eea24f395539eb4/llvmlite-0.31.0-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (15.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.9MB 1.1MB/s 

Installing collected packages: llvmlite

Successfully installed llvmlite-0.31.0
```

Answer (score 7):

You will have to install the required llvm package using and link the executable config

```
sudo apt install llvm-**X**
```

and then

```
sudo pip3 install llvmlite 
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s llvm-config-**X** llvm-config
```

This fixed the llvm issue of installing librosa on my raspberry pi (aarch64)

Comment: What "X" did you use for your installation? Also, could you list the versions of numpy, numba, llvmlite, and librosa on your pi that ultimately were installed?

Comment: It is the version number you have installed. e.g. **X** should be replaced with 10.0.0 if you have that version installed. 
I am sorry, I do not still have the environment I initially used. But I recall using numpy 1.16, librosa 0.7.X and lvmlite 7. Make sure your numba version is supported for the lvmlite

Comment: I was able to get it to work with LLVM-7, numpy 1.16.1, numba 0.49.0, llvmlite 0.32.0, and librosa 0.8.0! 

I think you can get newer LLVM versions to work, but you need to scale numba and llvmlite to match compatibility. Raspbian has an easily installable LLVM-7, so I went with the versions I mention above.

Comment: In my case, for Ubuntu 18.04/Mint 19.3, I used `apt install llvm-10`, and then set the new `llvm-config` link. Then it worked! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286131/how-do-i-install-llvm-10-on-ubuntu-18-04/1286132

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.

> You will have to install the required llvm package using and link the executable config
>
> sudo apt install llvm-**X**
>
> and then
>
> sudo pip3 install llvmlite
> cd /usr/bin
> sudo ln -s llvm-config-**X** llvm-config

did not work for me but I did notice we had the same output error

```
RuntimeError: <path> failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
```

So I thought: "why not point the `LLVM_CONFIG` to the proper `llvm-config`?".

And I did this simple fix:

```sh
export LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-10
```

Comment: For macOS, use `brew install llvm@9` and then `LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/local/opt/llvm@9/bin/llvm-config` (or similar for other LLVM versions)

Comment: This worked for me _(note paths are different and LDFLAGS was important too)_
```export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@11/lib" LLVM_CONFIG="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@11/bin/llvm-config" pip install numba```

Answer (score 0):

Running `llvm-config`, I got:

```
llvm-config: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

That seemed to be causing the problem, so after a quick search I found [a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674104/clang-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libtinfo-so-5-cannot-open-shared-o) that provided this fix:

```bash
$ sudo apt install libncurses5
```

After running `pip install llvmlite` again it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
conda activate
conda create --name py37 python=3.7  # or just conda install python==3.7
```

And then the rest. I already had all the dependencies, when I got the errors you mentioned.